# HP Officejet 4620 printer won't print black even with new cartridge

Tags: printer

My printer shows I have black ink and I have even put in a new cartridge to make sure.  I am using HP cartridges so don't have the issues with a compatible cartridge. It will print in color but not in black.  Can someone tell me what the issue might be?

Answer (score 2):

In the [user manual](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-officejet-4620-e-all-in-one-printer-series/5101229/model/5101234/manuals), in the section of [troubleshooting](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Officejet-4620-e-All-in-One-Printer/5101229/model/5101234/document/c03944809/) you can find the instructions to troubleshot the problem:

**Solution six: Print and evaluate a Print Quality Diagnostic Report**
Follow these steps to print and then evaluate the Print Quality Diagnostic Report.

- Step one: Print the report Load plain white U.S. letter or A4 size
  paper in the tray.
- On the control panel home screen, press the Setup icon .
- Press the button  next to the Down Arrow  until Reports displays next
  to OK.
- Press the button next to OK to select Reports.
- Press the button next to the Down Arrow  until Print Quality Report
  displays next to OK, and then press the button next to OK.
- The report prints.